# Further expanding upon definitions in set theory?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Consider the set $A=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and the set $B=\{0,-1,-2,-3,-4\}$. I am working with these sets. I need help clearing up some formal logic notation. I know that $\{x:x ∈ A\}=A$
is true. I know that this translates to "The set of x elements such that x is an element of A"  I would like to try and expand this definition with these different scenarios. Can you tell me if I am right?

$$$$

$\{x:x ∈ B , 3x ∈ A \}=B\cup3A= \{0,3,6,9,12,15,-1,-2,-3,-4\}$ is this statement true? I just took this to be the union. Please let me know if I am right? Or if I am wrong could you please elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: "$ \in B , 3x \in A$" --- Usually when a comma is used in this manner it represents "and", but you seem to be using the comma to represent "or" (but not exactly). Personally, I prefer to avoid the use of commas like this (note how the use of a comma in [roster notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Roster_notation) is entirely different) and just say explicitly "and", "or", or whatever the case may be.

Comment: No; $\{ x : x∈B,3x∈A \}$ is the set of those element of $B$ such that $3x$ is an element of $A$. Thus, only $0$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: Thank you. I am still learning this.

Comment: I think that is what they mean. The comma must be an and symbol. I though that it was completly arbitrary. Thanks for the help. I am understanding this a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{x: x \in B, 3x \in A\}$ would mean those $x$ that lie in $B$ and **at the same time** whose triple-value is in $A$. In your sets $A$ and $B$ as given, only $0$ obeys this so that set would be simply the same as $\{0\}$.

I think it's clearer to mention $B$ in the left "defining" clause and $3x\in A$ as the restricting clause after ":", so as

$$\{x \in B: 3x \in A\} = \{0\}$$

You could also make the *and* explicit so write

$\{x : x \in B \land 3x \in A\}$

I prefer the first one though, as it makes the appeal to the Axiom of Comprehension more explicit.
What you wrote as $3A$ you could write as $\{3x: x \in A\}$ more accurately.
But $3x \in A$ is a *condition* on $x$, not an instruction to take all tripled values of $x$ from $A$..

This $\{\cdot : \cdot \}$ notation is quite flexible, and common. Also used for ranges of functions so we can  write $\{f(x) : x \in A\}$ as $f[A]$ for a certain function, say. You can read the part after ":" as "such that .... holds", so there should be some condition there.